# Why does map function return undefined but console.log logs out?

Tags: javascript

I want to return matching proprieties of two arrays of objects. But I got undefined from map function.

```
let fruits1 = [
    {id: 1, name: "apple"},
    {id: 2, name: "dragon fruit"},
    {id: 3, name: "banana"},
    {id: 4, name: "kiwi"},
    {id: 5, name: "pineapple"},
    {id: 6, name: "watermelon"},
    {id: 7, name: "pear"},
]
let fruits2 = [
    {id: 7, name: "pear"},
    {id: 10, name: "avocado"},
    {id: 5, name: "pineapple"},
]

fruits1.forEach((fruit1) => {
    fruits2.filter((fruit2) => {
        return fruit1.name === fruit2.name;
    }).map((newFruit) => {
        //console.log(newFruit.name);
        return newFruit.name;
    })
})
```

Comment: The `.map()` function returns a new array, but your code does not use the return value.

Comment: also `Foreach` returns undeifed  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: `fruits2.filter(o=> fruits1.some(i=> i.name == o.name) ).map(o=> o.name);`

Comment: Is it just me, or is it a slight code smell that the elements have an "id", but that's not what is being used in the comparison?  Maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

```
/* first we filter fruits1 (arbitrary) */
let matchingFruits = fruits1.filter(f1 => {
  /* then we filter the frut if it exists in frtuis2 */
  return fruits2.find(f2 => f2.name === f1.name)
}).map(fruit => fruit.name) // and now we map if we only want the name strings
```

If you're not using a polyfill [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will not work in IE. The alternative would be using [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (thanks for pointing this out @JakobE).

Be aware that [Array.forEach return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) is `undefined` and that, in order to actually use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) correctly, one has to consume the returned value somehow or assign it to a variable, as we just did with `matchingFruits`.

Comment: Note! 'find' is not supported by IE

Comment: let matchingFruits = fruits1.filter(item => fruits2.map(item => item.name).indexOf(item.name)!== -1).map(item => item.name);

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is an **array intersection**:

```
// Generic helper function that can be used for the three operations:        
const operation = (list1, list2, isUnion = false) =>
    list1.filter( a => isUnion === list2.some( b => a.name === b.name ) );

// Following functions are to be used:
const inBoth = (list1, list2) => operation(list1, list2, true),
      inFirstOnly = operation,
      inSecondOnly = (list1, list2) => inFirstOnly(list2, list1);
```

**Usage:**

```
console.log('inBoth:', inBoth(list1, list2));
```

**Working Example:**

```js
// Generic helper function that can be used for the three operations:        
const operation = (list1, list2, isUnion = false) =>
    list1.filter( a => isUnion === list2.some( b => a.name === b.name ) );

// Following functions are to be used:
const inBoth = (list1, list2) => operation(list1, list2, true),
      inFirstOnly = operation,
      inSecondOnly = (list1, list2) => inFirstOnly(list2, list1);

let fruits1 = [
    {id: 1, name: "apple"},
    {id: 2, name: "dragon fruit"},
    {id: 3, name: "banana"},
    {id: 4, name: "kiwi"},
    {id: 5, name: "pineapple"},
    {id: 6, name: "watermelon"},
    {id: 7, name: "pear"},
]
let fruits2 = [
    {id: 7, name: "pear"},
    {id: 10, name: "avocado"},
    {id: 5, name: "pineapple"},
]

console.log('inBoth:', inBoth(fruits1, fruits2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the names.

```js
const names = ({ name }) => name;

var fruits1 = [{ id: 1, name: "apple" }, { id: 2, name: "dragon fruit" }, { id: 3, name: "banana" }, { id: 4, name: "kiwi" }, { id: 5, name: "pineapple" }, { id: 6, name: "watermelon" }, { id: 7, name: "pear" }],
    fruits2 = [{ id: 7, name: "pear" }, { id: 10, name: "avocado" }, { id: 5, name: "pineapple" }],
    common = fruits1
        .map(names)
        .filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(fruits2.map(names)));

console.log(common);
```